# beautifulsoup returns only partial urls for some websites

Tags: url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
    import requests

def get_url(url):
    page = requests.get(url.format()) 
    data = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

so that's the base code and when i request,

```
# get_url("https://www.marie-claire.es/moda")
get_url("http://spanish.xinhuanet.com/")
```

xinhua returns

[image]

full URLs,

but the other website
[image]

does not return the full hyperlinks,

I am not sure why I have this issue and how to solve it.
Has anyone had a similar issue? or has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: it's not an error or issue. It's how that particular site has it in the html. If it's a link within the root url, they don't include the root url.

Comment: Thank you! @chitown88

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're looking for *urljoin* here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def get_url(url):
    page = requests.get(url.format())
    data = page.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(urljoin(url, link.get('href')))
```

You might also consider

```
for link in set(soup.find_all('a')):
```

to avoid duplicates in your result.

Comment: Thank you @Rusticus!